# How to roll the axis forwards in numpy?

Tags: numpy

[`numpy.rollaxis`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.rollaxis.html) rolls the axis backwards. Suppose I have an `ndarray` with the shape `(3,640,480)` and I want to roll the first axis to the last, changing the shape to `(640,480,3)`. Can I do this easily? Although in this simple case two calls of `numpy.rollaxis` will work, if I have n axis this will be clumsy.

Comment: Did you try `numpy.rollaxis(my_array, 0, 3)`?

Comment: @MarkDickinson right, I didn't know the `start` be outside the index range.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an optional third argument, `start`, which tells where the axis should end up.  In this case, you want to move axis `0` before axis `3`:

```
>>> x.shape
(3,640,480)
>>> x2 = np.rollaxis(a,0,3)
>>> x2.shape
(640,480,3)
```

Comment: Oops, I didn't know it can be outside the index range.